# What word describes a person's worst flaw?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a word or phrase to describe the *worst* flaw that someone has? The closest thing I have found to what I'm looking for is *fatal flaw* (technically called *hamartia*), but that's a bit too specific:

> In tragedy, hamartia is the protagonist’s error or flaw that leads to a chain of plot actions culminating in a reversal from his/her good fortune to bad.
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamartia)

I'm not looking for a flaw that necessarily reverses someone's fortune, just a flaw that is worse than all of one's other flaws.

For example, John is disorganized, forgetful, and dishonest. If you think that dishonesty is John's *worst* flaw, you would say that dishonesty is John's __________.

Comment: I can't think of a single word, but I'd say *it was his greatest shortcoming*.

Comment: What is wrong with "worst flaw"?

Comment: How about _vice_?

Comment: @GEdgar Talking about people's *flaws* seems awfully judgemental.

Comment: @WS2 "Biggest weakness" sounds rather less judgemental. But I like "greatest shortcoming".

Comment: "Too humble" is my biggest flaw.

Comment: @HotLicks I thought that it was being the leader of the peanut gallery. :p

Comment: @Mazura - I'll have to check with Buffalo Bob on that.

Comment: Singular "failing"? `Dishonesty is John's failing.` Good question.

Comment: Interestingly, "hamartia" is the (koine) Greek word translated as "sin" in the Bible (both in the New Testament and the Septuagint). It literally means to "miss the mark", a term that comes from archery.

Comment: @insaner Interesting. I knew that it meant "miss the mark" but I didn't know that it could be translated as "sin." That seems incongruous with how it's used in tragedy--characters' fatal flaws are usually choices they make, such as being too ambitious, rather than inevitable human imperfection.

Comment: In the Bible, the word "sin" (hamartia) is used both to refer to the quality, or nature, of men descended from Adam (sometimes called "sinful nature" or "indwelling sin") but also to the action of sinning. Considering that it is sin that separates us infinitely from our Holy Creator (where "holy" here means "separated from all evil"), (cf, Isaiah 59:2) then, biblically speaking, this _is_ the ultimate downfall or fatal flaw, where we (all humans) _willingly_ choose to do evil (disobey God's perfect/good law), despite the eternal consequences of doing so.

Comment: @insaner All the person's flaws could be sins, that still doesn't single out the worst one. I don't think there's a single word answer to this question, we just use a superlative adjective to describe it.

Comment: @barmar, that would be asking "which sin is the worst", while the proposition by @Nicole is that the word `sin` describes the worst type of flaw. In other words: the worst _type_ of flaw is called "sin", but "sin" can be a reference to a _list_ of flaws itself. So, "running slowly" can be a flaw, but it's not "sin", while lying, stealing, murdering, all fall under "sin", because, (again, speaking biblically) any single one of those is your fatal flaw, since it separates you infinitely from God, the source of all that is good (cf James 1:17).

Comment: So yes, as an answer to the original question posted, "sin" isn't the sought for word, but @bib's "nadir" works pretty well, and was the one I found too.

Comment: @insaner Assuming the person is a liar, murderer and thief, the question asks for a word that refers to the worst of these sins. Just saying _sin_ doesn't single out murder, for instance.

Answer (score 16):

[Achilles' heel](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/achilles%27%20heel) may fit your description:

> - a fault or weakness that causes or could cause someone or something to fail.
>   (M-W)

- Dishonesty is John's Achilles' heel!

Comment: A person's fatal flaw would be their Achilles heel. Also, I don't think it gets an apostrophe unless you're talking about *his* foot.

Comment: @Mazura - It refers to *his* (Achilles') foot. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achilles%27_heel

Comment: So then, *an Achilles heel* doesn't get one and *your Achilles' heel* does?

Comment: Not only mine. Main dictionaries use it referring to its methaphorical meaning. Though it is also  used witout aphostrophe.

Comment: There's where I went first, but that's your greatest *weakness*, not flaw with ethical overtones.

Comment: flaw:  a fault, mistake, or weakness, especially one that happens while something is being planned or made, or that causes something not to be perfect.http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/flaw

Comment: It should have an apostrophe. It's possessive.

Comment: An Achilles' heel surely isn't necessarily a person's *worst* flaw. Hitler's Achilles' heel was his tendency to disregard his generals' advice and open up a two-front war. But that surely wasn't the worst thing you could say about him.

Answer (score 10):

> John is disorganized and forgetful, sure, but dishonesty may be his *undoing*.

Comment: I think "undoing" is more about something that will cause the person loss or hardship rather than being anything to do with being their "worst flaw". For example, "eating that sandwich was his undoing" has no implication of flaw.

Comment: @ChrisDown I see the distinction you're making. While _undoing_ might refer to one's greatest flaw, it could also refer to an event that had dire consequences for the person.

Answer (score 8):

For one word, how about ***downfall***?

Comment: Downfall may well be due to an external event rather than an personal attribute.

Answer (score 5):

*[Demon](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/demon)* could be a metaphorical expression for the extremely bad quality:

> n
>
> 2. a person, habit, obsession, etc, thought of as evil, cruel, or persistently tormenting

Answer (score 5):

You're getting hung up on the finality of "fatal flaw", and many of these suggestions have a similar problem - the implication that this flaw will inevitably lead to a person's undoing.  It's a difficult thing to untie from the concept of one's greatest flaw, since the strongest visual concept of a flaw that great is the fact that it can lead to a person's downfall.

I wouldn't worry about that implication, unless you very strongly want to untie it, because the use of such an idiom in english is usually figurative - a 'fatal flaw' doesn't necessarily mean the flaw **will** lead to a person's downfall, rather it only implies that the flaw is so great that it **could** lead to a person's downfall.

If you want to untie the concept of finality from this metaphor, you could try the expression "Key Flaw", which suggests a flaw that is more important and more disarming than any other flaw.  And you could also simply use the adjective of 'greatest' to indicate that it is in fact their "greatest flaw".  Both of these being a two-word phrase may not make it succinct, but the message of either phrase is quite clear.

As a final suggestion the [weakest link](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Weakest%20Link) refers to the most vulnerable part of a set, so if you're listing a person's characteristics or flaws, naming one as the 'weakest link' would indicate that it's the greatest flaw they have.  But you wouldn't individually call it the 'weakest link' unless you have something it would be related to.

Comment: +1 An excellent point about how language really works in communication. In almost any context, when one hears or reads that something is someone's fatal flaw, it will translate as "greatest flaw", and unless the idea of the flaw leading to death or downfall is explicitly evoked, that notion will not be evoked!

Answer (score 4):

You could use [bane](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bane) to express a person's worst flaw:

> 2 : a source of harm or ruin : curse

E.g.,

> Dishonesty is John's *bane*.

Or:

> Dishonesty is the *bane* of John's existence.

See [What is the origin and meaning of the phrase “bane of my existence”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/35708/8738)

Comment: Bane does not mean flaw.

Comment: Good answer; *bane* would be a good metonym for flaw to communicate the fact that it is the the one that ruins him. So far, two of the more popular answers use the same technique: *undoing & downfall*.

Answer (score 2):

**"John is disorganized and forgetful but, of all his flaws, dishonesty would prove his greatest *stumbling block*."**

> **STUMBLING BLOCK** *noun*
>
> In the Hebrew Bible, the term for "*stumbling block*" is mikshowl (מכשול), rendered in the Septuagint as skandalon (σκανδαλον). The English term "scandal" derives from this Septuagint Greek term skandalon, which in turn stands for the Hebrew mikshowl. The Greek term skandalon has little relation to the modern meaning of "scandal".
>
> The Greek noun skandalon also has an associated verb, skandalizo (formed with the -iz suffix as English "*scandalize*"), meaning literally "*to trip somebody up*" or, idiomatically, " *to cause someone to sin*."
>
> Apart from skandalon the idiom of "*stumbling block*" has a second synonym in the Greek term proskomma "stumbling." Both words are used together in 1 Peter 2:8; this is a "stone of stumbling" (lithos proskommatos λίθος προσκόμματος) and a "rock of offense" (petra skandalou πέτρα σκανδάλου). See, Wikipedia [“**stumbling block**"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stumbling_block)

**"John is disorganized and forgetful, but of all his flaws, in the end it was his dishonesty that would *snare* (or, *ensnare*) him."**

> **SNARE** *noun*: a thing likely to lure or tempt someone into harm or error; “the wickedness and *snares* of the Devil” see, OED [“**snare**”](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/snare)

Answer (score 2):

You could always try saying that it is his *weakness* or *failing*.

Without any adjectives, these words give the impression that they are the defining unpleasant trait of the person's character.

If you say his biggest or worst *failing/weakness*, it puts the other flaws on an equal footing, and only defines this as the biggest of relatively equal flaws.

> Whilst it was true that John was both disorganized and forgetful, his true weakness came from being dishonest.
>
> John was regularly forgetful and disorganized, but his failing as a man came from his dishonesty.

Whilst they are not particularly strong words in and of themselves (we talk about 'weaknesses' all the time), used in this way it separates the one biggest flaw from the others, to iterate the point that the particular flaw you are describing is much worse than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

While it is more often used to describe a process or series of events, you might consider *[nadir](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nadir)*

> The lowest point in the fortunes of a person or organization:
>   *they had reached the nadir of their sufferings*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

You might say something like

> While John is disorganized and forgetful, his dishonesty represents the nadir of  [in?] his character.

Comment: This is kind of a stretch... but I almost like it better than any of the other suggestions here. This is the only suggestion that talks about character flaw rather than just weakness or vulnerability.

Answer (score -1):

**Hubris** is extreme pride and arrogance shown by a character that ultimately brings about his downfall

In Greek tragedies, the “[*hubristic*](http://literarydevices.net/hamartia/)” actions of a hero, in a powerful position, causes his shame and humiliation.

**(**[*From literarydevices.net*](http://literarydevices.net/hamartia/)**)**

Comment: Hubris Might be an individuals worst flaw, but it certainly does not mean ' a person's worst flaw'.